# Insert Scrollbar into child ListBox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm attempting to insert a `Scrollbar` object into a `ListBox` object, when the `ListBox` object is a child of an existing window using Python's Tkinter library.

The vast majority of the Tkinter `Scrollbar` tutorials out there ([1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrollable-frames-in-tkinter/#)) put the `Scrollbar` object in a window that's directly a `ListBox`. I haven't seen one yet which places the `Scrollbar` into a `ListBox` that's a child inside of an existing window.

The following Python testing code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    mainWindow = tk.Tk(className = " TEST")
    mainWindow.geometry("300x300")

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(mainWindow)

    listBox = tk.Listbox(
        mainWindow,
        yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set,
    )
    listBox.place(x = 100, y = 100, anchor = "center")

    for i in range(100):
        listBox.insert(tk.END, "TEST")

    scrollbar.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)
    scrollbar.config(command = listBox.yview())

    mainWindow.resizable(False, False)
    mainWindow.mainloop()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Places the `Scrollbar` directly onto the right side of the main window, as such:

[image]

I'm assuming the `pack` function forces an element to one side of the parent window. If I try to specify the specific `Scrollbar` position using the `place` function instead, I cannot appear to change the height of the `Scrollbar`:

[image]

I thought of specifying the `listBox` object to the argument of the `ScrollBar` constructor (instead of `mainWindow`), however it appears that I cannot create the `ScrollBar` object after I create the `ListBox` object, because I need to provide the `ScrollBar` object to the `ListBox` constructor for the `yscrollcommand` field. It appears that I cannot change the `yscrollcommand` field after creating the `ListBox` object.

What is the proper way to place a `Scrollbar` object inside of a `ListBox` object that's a child of an existing window?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more easier to layout the listbox and scrollbar by putting them in a frame:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    mainWindow = tk.Tk(className="TEST")
    mainWindow.geometry("300x300")

    # frame for the listbox and scrollbar
    frame = tk.Frame(mainWindow)
    frame.place(x=50, y=50, anchor="nw")

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame)

    listBox = tk.Listbox(
        frame,
        yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set,
    )

    for i in range(100):
        listBox.insert(tk.END, "TEST")

    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    scrollbar.config(command=listBox.yview)
    listBox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    mainWindow.resizable(False, False)
    mainWindow.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use place() instead of pack like so:

```
import tkinter as tk

import tkinter as tk

def main():
    mainWindow = tk.Tk(className = " TEST")
    mainWindow.geometry("300x300")

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(mainWindow)

    listBox = tk.Listbox(
        mainWindow,
        yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set,
    )
    listBox.place(x = 100, y = 100, anchor = "center")

    for i in range(100):
        listBox.insert(tk.END, "TEST")

    scrollbar.place(in_=listBox, relx=1, relheight=1, bordermode="outside")
    scrollbar.config(command = listBox.yview())

    mainWindow.resizable(False, False)
    mainWindow.mainloop()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

In the place() method, the **_in** option is used to specify the widget relative to which the current widget will be placed.

**relx, rely** are the horizontal and vertical offset relative to the size of the parent widget, values between 0.0 and 0.1

**relwidth, relheight** are the set height and width of widget relative to the size of the parent widget, values between 0.0 and 0.1

Answer (score 0):

Edited: I left out 2.

I do work around to make an easier.

Use `pack()` instead of `place()`

The `"TEST"` replace with `i`.

snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

#Create an instance of Tkinter Frame
def main():
    mainWindow = tk.Tk(className = " TEST")

    #Set the geometry of Tkinter Frame
    mainWindow.geometry("700x350")

    #Create a vertical scrollbar
    scrollbar= tk.Scrollbar(mainWindow, orient= 'vertical')
    scrollbar.pack(side= tk.RIGHT, fill= tk.BOTH)

    #Add a Listbox Widget
    listbox = tk.Listbox(mainWindow, width= 350, bg= 'bisque')
    listbox.pack(side= tk.LEFT, fill= tk.BOTH)

    for i in range(100):
       listbox.insert(tk.END, i)

    listbox.config(yscrollcommand= scrollbar.set)
    #Configure the scrollbar
    scrollbar.config(command= listbox.yview)

    mainWindow.resizable(False, False)
    mainWindow.mainloop()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```